# How to use GPUBatch.draw_instanced in python API

Tags: python, scripting

How to use `draw_instanced` in python API, how to understand the purpose of this function

Template for drawing a 2D rectangle in the viewport:

```
# Can't run in old blender version, suppose blender 3.4 +
import bpy, gpu
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader
from gpu.matrix import get_projection_matrix

vert_out = gpu.types.GPUStageInterfaceInfo("my_interface")
shader_info = gpu.types.GPUShaderCreateInfo()
shader_info.push_constant('MAT4', "viewProjectionMatrix")
shader_info.push_constant('VEC4', "color")
shader_info.vertex_in(0, 'VEC2', "position")
shader_info.fragment_out(0, 'VEC4', "FragColor")

shader_info.vertex_source('''
    void main() {
        gl_Position = viewProjectionMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    }
''')

shader_info.fragment_source('''
    void main() {
        FragColor = color ;
    }
''')

shader = gpu.shader.create_from_info(shader_info)
del shader_info

left = 50
right = 200
bottom = 50
top = 200

batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'TRIS', {"position": (
    (left, bottom), (right, bottom), (right, top),
    (right, top), (left, top), (left, bottom)
)})

def draw():
    shader.uniform_float("viewProjectionMatrix", get_projection_matrix())
    shader.uniform_float("color", (1, 1, 1, 1))
    batch.draw(shader)

bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
# Need to manually update the viewport: like pan the viewport
```